# Arduino - Running an if condition for a certain amount of time

Tags: c++, arduino

Currently working on a project where I need to turn on the motor for just 1 second if my rain sensor detects any rain. if no rain I will again rote backward for 1 second.
sensor and device that I'm using
Arduino MEGA
Rain Sensor
L298N Motor driver

but the problem is I'm unable to run the condition for 1 second.

Here is my current Arduino sketch

```
const int IN1 = 7;
const int IN2 = 6;
const int ENA = 9;
const int capteur_A = A0;
int val_analogique;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(capteur_A, INPUT);
  pinMode (IN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (IN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (ENA, OUTPUT);

}

void forward(){
  analogWrite(ENA, 60);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  }


void loop() {

val_analogique=analogRead(capteur_A); 
Serial.println(val_analogique);

 if(val_analogique<=300){
  forward();
  Serial.println("Going Forward");
 }

 else{
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
 }

}
```

Comment: What do `IN1` and `IN2` and `ENA` and `capteur_A` do?

Comment: IN1 and IN2 are for giving the command to the motor driver to rotate clockwise and anticlockwise. capteur_A  store rain sensor value

Answer (score 0):

To let the Motor rotate for 1 second, you just have to wait and then stop it. You can use the delay() function to wait a specific number of milliseconds. The forward function would be:

```
void forward() {
    analogWrite(ENA, 60);  // Set power and direction for the motor
    digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);

    delay(1000);   // Wait for 1000 milliseconds

    digitalWrite(ENA, 0);  // Stop the motor
    digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
}
```

And for the other direction it would be exactly the same, just with the two direction ports swapped:

```
void backward() {
    analogWrite(ENA, 60);  // Set power and direction for the motor
    digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);

    delay(1000);   // Wait for 1000 milliseconds

    digitalWrite(ENA, 0);  // Stop the motor
    digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
}
```

Oh, and by the way, it would also be nice to call the ports OUT and not IN, as they're outputs and not inputs :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement a simple state machine pseudo code as a starter:

```
    long timer = 0;
    bool conditionRain = false;
    bool conditionNoRain = true;

    setup() {}

    loop() {
     ...
         if(val_analogique<=300 && conditionRain == false) { // Condition rain detected
         timer = millis();  // we start the timer
         conditionRain = true;  // set the state
         conditionNoRain = false;   // set the state
    }

    if (conditionRain == true && millis()-timer < 1000) { // Here is the timer check
        ... do motor for rain ...
    }

    // Assumption Since the motor should run for one second when the rain stops
    if(val_analogique>=850 && conditionNoRain == false){ // Condition rain detected
        timer = millis();
        conditionRain = false;  // set the state
        conditionNoRain = true; // set the state
    }

    if (conditionNoRain == true && millis()-timer<1000){ // Here is the timer check
        ... do motor for no rain ...
    }
```

Simple switching between states with timer function -there is no else because we always check the states if these are not fulfilled nothing should happen

Comment: To the minus voters whats wrong with this solution for an obvious newbee. Feedback appriciated